# Getting Error While setting icon in List : Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Getting Error While setting icon in Top 3 row of list

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var navItems = document.getElementsByClassName("icon");
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    navItems[i].innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #ff8944;font-size: 19px;"></i>'
  }
});
```

Comment: Why not simply `$(".icon")` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName("icon")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using plain JS DOM manipulation, such errors are common if such an element could not be retrieved from the DOM (since it's like doing: `undefined.innerHTML =` )

- **No need to loop anything** if you use `$("selector").html()` jQuery will loop your elements collections internally.
- Use jQuery (since you're already using it) - it will fail silently if no *`.icon`* elements were found
- Don't use inline `style` attributes

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".icon").html('<i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>')
});
```

```css
.icon .fa {
  color: #ff8944;
  font-size: 19px;
}
```

```html
No ".item" in DOM - Will not show errors.

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```